# PL/SQL How insert a Variable in delete partition command?

Tags: sql, database, plsqldeveloper

how pass a variable name at command delete partition in pl/sql?for example:

```
DECLARE
   x varchar2 := 'hello';
BEGIN
ALTER TABLE t1 delete PARTITION(X);
END
```

is possible?

Answer (score 1):

```
DECLARE
   x varchar2 := 'hello';
BEGIN
   execute immediate 'alter table t1 delete partition('||x||')';
END;
```